# python ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 109 target samples

Tags: python

Writing a program, use `Conv2D` in `keras` to predict a series of data(regression), the training dataset in input layer  is 109 dataset and 5 parameters (109*5, the 5 parameters are solar intensity, ambient temperatue, etc), the number need to predict is the output layer include 2 parameters(thermal efficiency and heat transfer efficiency),the program is as follows:

```py
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(109,5,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(32))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['mse','mae'])

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    ...
    x1 = sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train
    sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D = x1.reshape([1,x1.shape[0], x1.shape[1],1])
    y1 = sc_cnn_tube_eff_Y_train
    y_res = np.concatenate((y1,sc_cnn_tube_h_Y_train),axis=1)
    print("sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D.shape")
    print(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D.shape)
    print("y_res.shape")
    print(y_res.shape)
    model = model()
    model.fit(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D,y_res,epochs=5000,verbose=1)
```

the `sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D` in the training dataset, I set it as 1*109*5*1, the `y_yes` is the two parameters need to predict in training process, it is 109*2, the first column is thermal efficiency, the second column is heat transfer coefficient, all the data have been normalized

when running:

```
    sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D.shape
    (1, 109, 5, 1)
    y_res.shape
    (109, 2)
```

but it errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/win/PycharmProjects/allGlassStraightThroughTube/cnn2DTest.py", line 280, in <module>
        model.fit(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_4D,y_res,epochs=5000,verbose=1)
      ...
      ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 109 target samples.
```

could you please tell the reason and how to correct it
and please help me to correct the program, because I am a freshman for convolutional neural network using `keras`.

Comment: Have you considered using the functional API? I think it may help with multiple inputs. On the other hand, what is the datatype of the inputs? Are they images or numbers?

Comment: the datatype of the inputs are float, they are all numbers,not images,the input include 5 parameters including solar intensity,ambient temperature and etc,total 109 dataset, I want uase these data to predict the thermal efficiency and heat transfer coefficient(two parameters, they are all numbers), so I think it is using cnn to regression, not classification,

Comment: and how to use function API, could you please tell me

Comment: I am a little confused as how you structured your model. When dealing with purely numbers, Conv2D makes no sense as it only works with two dimensional data. As for the functional API, here is a link https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional. Using it more multiple inputs is quite simple. You will just need to specify multiple input layers and concatenate all of them later.